# Npm executables names collision

Tags: npm, executable

When making my package, which has
an executable in it,
how do I avoid name collisions with another packages,
who provides executables with the same name?

I've even made an experiment:

1. created package **foo** with `{"bin": {"baz": "./bin/baz"}}` in package.json
2. created package **bar** with `{"bin": {"baz": "./bin/baz"}}` in package.json
3. created package **quux** with `{"dependencies": {"foo": "../foo", "bar": "../bar"}}`
4. checked quux/node_modules/.bin: it contains only one `baz` executable of the last installed package (bar), i.e. it overwrote (silently!) the first `baz` executable, which is unacceptable.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Actually - as far as I've noticed, this problem is far more grave.
I have a module `tsd` installed which has a dependency called `@tsd/typescript` which provides a `tsc`-executable.

Even though, `@tsd/typescript` isn't a direct dependency of my package, my `node_modules/.bin/tsc` is overwritten with a file pointing to `@tsd/typescript` rather than `typescript`.

I think I'll have to create an issue